# FileProvider authority in android library project

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library, android-fileprovider

In a [library project](https://github.com/jonasrottmann/realm-browser/issues/20) I'm using a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) with my libraries applicationId as its authority. Now when somebody uses this library e.g. in two flavors of his app, the second one will not install because of conflicting FileProviders.

**Goal**

Being able to define a unique authority for my libraries FileProvider for each variant of an application.

**First Approach**

Im appending a random int to the authority, which works just fine.

*build.gradle*

```
static def generateContentProviderAuthority() {
    Random random = new Random()
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append("application.id.of.my.library")
            .append(".fileprovider")
            .append(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100000)))
            .toString()
}


defaultConfig {
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders= [contentProviderAuthority: generateContentProviderAuthority()]
}
```

*Manifest*

```
<provider
    android:name=".helper.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
</provider>
```

But now the manifest changes every build, which messes with instant run and stuff...

**Solution**

Is it possible to get the exact applicationId of the application which uses the library in my libraries build.gradle?

Comment: I put the `<provider>` element in the app's manifest, or at least have the app's manifest supply the `android:authorities` value (via manifest merger). That way, particularly if you mangle `${applicationId}` into the `android:authorities` value, the authority string can be unique, even if multiple apps use the library. The library then derives the authority string off of `getPackageName()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to do just that, but in order to access a file (`FileProvider.getUriForFile`) I need access to the authority as `String`. Do you know how I can get it? Since I am using the `FileProvider` in a library module that may be used in any app I have no access to `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkusPenguin: The safest thing is to have a method in your library that the hosting app calls to give you the authority string. You can try `getPackageName()` as I mentioned, but AFAIK that assumes that the app is not changing the application ID based on build variant.

Answer (score 7):

As CommonsWare mentioned in the comment, it is enough to use dynamic `${applicationId}` in the `authorities` section.

```
<provider
    android:name=".ScreenshotFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.library.name.screenshots"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

More thorough explanation at CommonsWare's blog:
https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/27/fileprovider-libraries.html

Comment: When using `FileProvider.getUriForFile` I'll still need to provide the authority. Do you know how I can get it? `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` is not available, because I am using the provider in a module that may be included in any app project.

Answer (score 0):

In library manifest put code like below:

```
<provider
android:name="YOUR LIBRARY FILE PROVIDER CLASS"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.library.file.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
    tools:node="merge" />
```

Then have a class like below in your sdk and then initialise it with context from consumer application or from your sdk content provider.

```
object SDK {

  lateinit var fileProviderAuthority: String

  fun init(context: Context) {
   fileProviderAuthority = "${context.packageName}.library.file.provider"
  }

}
```

When you need the fileAuthority string for file uri operations consume it like below:

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, SDK.fileProviderAuthority,File(FILE_PATH))
```

To read more click [here](https://rajeshtechgeek.medium.com/how-to-setup-custom-file-provider-in-a-android-library-to-avoid-collision-436a206a2c11)